# VueJS - what's the difference between main.js - app.vue and component.vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just got started to Vue and i added it to my Django project using Webpack-Loader, so i'm not creating a SPA, and i have some very basic doubts about the structure of vue.

I have a component that i added to one of my HTML templates, it's a very basic datatable made with Vuetify, the full code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-goldwasser-gfl7x?file=/src/App.vue

What is not very clear to me, yet, is the whole **component.vue -> app.vue -> main.js** mechanism.
In this case if i want to use that component i created on a template, i will just add the following to the template:

```
<div id="app">
    <app></app>
</div>
```

But what happens when i want to create a new component? Suppose that i created another component and i want to use it on the same or another page of my Django project, what do i need to do? Do i have to create another app.vue for every component? Do i have to create another main.js file for the component? Or do i need to use only one app.vue and one main.js for all my components?
Thanks in advance for any kind of advice!

Comment: No. Your `app.vue` is the main VueJS App, and it is through this file that you load whatever components that you need to use. There should only be one `app.vue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation this is what happens:

- Your django page includes your main.js (or the bundle that was created for main.js).
- main.js start looking for an element with id #app
- it will fill it with `<App />` because you told it to do so (via the template property)

You asked if you now have to do component.vue -> app.vue -> main.js for each new component you create. Currently, yes, because your main.js isn't setup to be flexible. To make main.js more flexible you could do the following:

```
import App from 'App.vue';
Vue.component('app', App);

import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent.vue';
Vue.component('another-component', AnotherComponent);

// Here you tell Vue to look for an element with an id #app.
// But by not supplying it a template it will use the content 
// of #app as template.
// The django page may now determine what you want Vue to do.
new Vue({
  el: "#app", 

  // template: '' // Let django page determine.
  // components: { App } // use Vue.component to register components globally instead.

  vuetify: Vuetify // when you want to use Vuetify.
});
```

I hope this made Vue a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking your time to answer! It surely made Vue clearer. So with the code you provided, i would have a single main.js and more components  Forgive me if i'm wrong, with this setup i would add a new component with another el: #app02 that should go below el: '#app', right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this is more useful in different situations. You would add more components (that do different things for instance) and register them via Vue.component.

Comment: And then your django page you tell Vue what to show you, 

on django page 1 you do: `<div id="app"><my-datatable></my-datatable></div>` and on django page 2 you do `<div id="app"><some-nice-report></some-nice-report></div>`

Comment: One last thing i promise! In my case, how can i load the "dtable" component that i created (see my sandbox) on a HTML template? Because i tried <div id="app"><dtable></dtable></div> but it doesn't seem to find the component with that name

Comment: You should register it first with vue, in main.js, like so `import dtable from "./components/dtable"; Vue.component("dtable", dtable);` . After this you can do 
<div id="app"><dtable></dtable></div>